# Remote desktop "Launch initial program" doesn't work

Tags: remote-desktop, group-policy, debug

Terminal Services Configuration RDP-Tcp v6.1 Environment setting:
Run initial program specified by user profile and Remote Desktop Connection or client

1. Run mstsc.exe on the client
2. Enter the server address on the General tab
3. Enable "Start the following program on connection" in the Programs tab
4. Enter "c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe" without quotes in the "Program path and file name" field
5. Enter "c:\windows\system32" without quotes in the "Start in the following folder" field
6. Click Connect
7. Enter the password and click OK
8. Click Yes to connect to the server despite the certificate error
9. A connection to the server was successfully established and user is logged in

**However, notepad.exe is not launched in the remote desktop connection window.**

How can I fix this?

---

Client: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1, mstsc.exe v6.1.7601.17514

Server: Windows Server 2008 Datacenter v6.0.6002 SP2 (Hosted on Amazon EC2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May read this ?

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverTS/thread/2b55ff33-3706-44e4-88a6-19c0b140cd25

Comment: From there: http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/79577-remote-desktop-start-program-connection.html

Comment: Thank you.  I had to install the Terminal Services Role and add notepad.exe as an allowed RemoteApp program.

Comment: @bZezzz, 17k views to this question and only one upvote.... If only you had dressed up this answer better you would have had 30 upvotes.